SQL: join 2 tables based on several conditions "on"
I have two tables:
Table 1: variable ID



Name
IDvariable1
IDvaria2




Peter
A
1


Carl
B
2


Maria
C
3



Table2: variables ID + definition



IDvariable1
Descr Var1
IDvariable2
Descr Var2




A
Car
1
Diesel


B
Motorbike
2
Electric


C
Bycicle
2
Electric


A
Car
3
Fuel



Problem: import definition of the variables of table 1, contained in the table2, into table 1
I expect following joining table where the definition of the variables included in table 2 are imported to table 1.



Name
IDvariable1
Descr Var1
IDvariable2
Descr Var2




Peter
A
Car
1
Diesel


Carl
B
Motorbike
2
Electric


Maria
C
Bycicle
2
Electric


...
A
Car
3
Fuel



Would this be correct?
proc sql;
create table Listcars as select distinct
t1.name,
t1.IDvariable1,
t2.Descr Var1,
t1.IDvaria2,
t2.Descr Var2,
from Table1 as t1
left join Table2 as t2
on t1.IDvariable1=t2.IDvariable1
and t1.IDvaria2=t2.IDvariable2;
quit;


What database solution are you using? Your answers will vary some based on that. You should edit your OP to add the correct tag.

Also, assuming your table data is not complete as there is a record looking for a bicycle and fuel in the first table. Maria, C, 3. Is your second table a combination of all vehicles and their respective fuel types? If so, the vehicles should have their own table and the fuel types their own table, and table two should only serve to relate the two to each other.

Thank you Clearly. Comment 1: I added sql code. Comment 2: Maria, C, 3 should be MAria, bycicle, fuel. The combination is nonsense, forget it. The important thing is that C=bycicle and 3 = fuel, always. And i want them in imported in table 1.

What db are you using?

And again, is it realistic to expect that ALL of the possible combinations will be in this table? It seems like this table should be two different tables. For example, will C,3 be in table 2 to lookup? If it is not, should we exclude that row from table 1? If you want to include all of the rows in table 1 regardless of if they have a match, then yes, your query will work. If not, then no it will not.  Note however, there appears to be something fundamentally incorrect in your setup and this could be better normalized.
